# TypeScript, Lambda handler, Conversion of type for APIGatewayProxyEvent

Tags: aws-lambda, typescript-typings, aws-serverless

I have this code, that it's part of a test for a Lambda handler (Serverless Framework):

```
// some code
const event = {
  queryStringParameters: {
    documentType: PersonalDocumentType.RUT,
    destinationCountry: 'COL'
  }
} as APIGatewayProxyEvent;
AWSMock.setSDKInstance(AWS);
AWSMock.mock(
  'DynamoDB.DocumentClient',
  'get',
  (
    params: QueryInput,
    callback: (error?: AWSError, data?: DynamoDocument.GetItemOutput) => void
  ) => {
    dynamoGetMock(params);
    callback(undefined, outputEvent);
  });

const handlerResponse = await handler(event);
// more code
```

I have a type error:

```
 TS2352: Conversion of type '{ queryStringParameters: { documentType: PersonalDocumentType; destinationCountry: string; }; }' to type 'APIGatewayProxyEvent' may be a mistake because neither type sufficient
ly overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
      Type '{ queryStringParameters: { documentType: PersonalDocumentType; destinationCountry: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'APIGatewayProxyEventBase<APIGatewayEventDefaultAuthorizerContext>': body, headers, multiValueHeaders, httpMethod
, and 7 more.
```

It seems that the `event` const that I'm creating needs more properties, but how could I pass each property? I don't thinks that's the solution. Any idea?